# ROS doesn't see numpy

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu, ros

I tried different ways of installation of **numpy**, but the problem that I'm facing is: there is no `numpy` in the list when I call *rospack list-names*. Even with installed numpy, when I can see its version and location, ROS still cannot find it and **gives me error that no such module is found**.

I tried installing through different environments like pip, pipenv and normally (sudo apt ...).
Maybe there is some way to show ROS where to find a package?

Comment: numpy is not a ROS package so you will never see it in rospack. module not found is a python problem, not a ROS one.You probably installed numpy in a different python version than ROS is using.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is using python3 with Melodic or other Ros distro which doesn't work with python3. This command may be solve:

```
pip2 install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see `numpy` as a ROS package because it has no ROS installation procedure at all. Just try to type:

```bash
python3
import numpy
```

If you would see an error, then you need to check `numpy` is installed on your system. Then you do not have to list it in your `package.xml`, but you can [find the component `Python::NumPy`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html) in `CMakeLists.txt` once you have CMake version 3.14 or newer.